# ajax how to convert below email Realtime check to number validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to Realtime validation for 1 particular input felid that can check 12 digits number and cross check is this number already stored in database. now I was having below code which can validate and check unic email id excised from database email validation with i was used this code from this tutorial link https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/live-email-availability-in-laravel-using-ajax.html.

**my input now it was having email**

```
<div class="form-control-wrap">
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-outlined form-control-outlined" id="email" name="email" >
 <label class="form-label-outlined" for="email">email</label>
  <span id="error_email"></span>
 </div>
```

**my ajax code now it was having email**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#email').blur(function(){
  var error_email = '';
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if(!filter.test(email))
  {    
   $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-danger">Invalid Email</label>');
   $('#email').addClass('has-error');
   $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else
  {
   $.ajax({
      
    url:"{{ url('https://test.com/email_available/check') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{email:email, _token:_token},
    success:function(result)
    {
     if(result == 'unique')
     {
      $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-success">Email Available</label>');
      $('#email').removeClass('has-error');
      $('#register').attr('disabled', false);
     }
     else
     {
      $('#error_email').html('<label class="text-danger">Email not Available</label>');
      $('#email').addClass('has-error');
      $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
    }
   })
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this function on email input field on key up jquery event like this:**

```
$("#email").on("keyup", function(e) {
    // do stuff!
})
```